# How can i get from a listView1 item(file) the file full path?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this in my designer:

[image: Explorer]

On the right is the files in a listView1.
On the left is the directory main directory of this files treeView1.

I have this code in menu strip item clicked event :

```
        void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
            {
                List<String> selected = new List<String>();
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    selected.Add(lvi.Text);
                }
                AllFiles = selected.ToArray();
                Bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the file/s in AllFiles array are only the filenames for example: bootmgr or install.exe

But i need that in the All Files each file will have also it's full path for example:

> c:\bootmgr or c:\install.exe or c:\test\test\example.txt

How can i add to AllFiles also the paths ?

I tried now:

```
void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
            {
                List<String> selected = new List<String>();
                string dir = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    string g = Path.Combine(dir, lvi.Text);
                    selected.Add(g);
                }

                AllFiles = selected.ToArray();
                Bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

And in form1:

```
private void FtpProgress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            f = new FtpSettings();
            f.Host = "ftP://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com";
            f.Username = "...";
            f.Password = "...";
            files = TV_LV_Basic.ExplorerTree.AllFiles;
            StringArrayUploadFiles(sender, e);
        }
```

AllFiles contain the files and paths for example C:\test.txt

Then :

```
private void StringArrayUploadFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string txf in files)
                {
                    string fn = txf;
                    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                    if (f.TargetFolder != "" && f.TargetFolder != null)
                    {
                        createDirectory(f.TargetFolder);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f.TargetFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(txf);
                        //createDirectory(f.TargetFolder);
                    }
                    string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(fn));
```

Now in txf for example i have C:test.txt
Then in f.TargetFolder i have: C:

Then in UploadPath i have: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/C:/eula.1031.txt
But instead C: i need it to look like: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/C/eula.1031.txt

And there are sub directories for example then: ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/C/Sub/Dir/eula.1031.txt

In the menuStrip1_ItemClicked event when i select a file for example test.txt already in this event i did a mess.

Comment: Separate the data from the view.

Comment: Surely you must already know the folder these files belong to, how else would you have populated the ListView?  Store that path at Class level when you populate the ListView and use System.IO.Path.Combine() to put them back together when you add them to the List.  Alternatively, just store the full path in the Tag() property of the ListViewItem when you create it.

Comment: Likr Idle_Mind suggests put the extra info in the `ListViewItem.Tag`! Best the whole `FileInfo` objects..

Comment: I had to add more code to my question to explain what i'm trying to get. When  i select a file on the listView1 i need to get the directory of the file but only the name for example C:\\ so only C and if the directory is dannyistest:\\daniel\\hello then it should be: dannyistest/daniel/hello/test.txt since i'm uploading the file to my ftp srver so this is how the format of the directory should be like.

Comment: The point which people here mentioned is that data representation can be different from the storage. You should store as much information as you need, to do your stuff, then only show a portion of it to the user. You can gradually build a "state" object as your program goes though processing stages. By the time you update UI, you should have enough information to do your next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("temp.txt");
```

Determine the full path of the file just created.

```
        DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
```

Figure out what other entries are in that directory.

```
 FileSystemInfo[] fsi = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
```

to display directoryinfo fullname in console

```
Console.WriteLine("The directory '{0}' contains the following files and directories:", di.FullName);
```

Print the names of all the files and subdirectories of that directory.

```
        foreach (FileSystemInfo info in fsi)
            Console.WriteLine(info.Name);
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/581030/Fileinfopluserrorplus-plustoopluslongpluspath)